# read file in php and insert into ec2 amazon server mysql database

Tags: php

actually im having list of medicine in a file and i want to insert it on ec2 amazon server database which is mysql.I run this file on localhost.when im trying my code, which is in php it show an error as follows:im not getting.

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (10060) in C:\websites\medicine\filehandling.php on line 17
Can't connect to MySQL
This is a servername:ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
here is my code... and let me know where im wrong.

```
<?php

$hostname='http://ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com';
//$port='3306';
$user='root';//// specify username
$pass='bitnami'; //// specify password
$dbase='fortis'; //// specify database name
set_time_limit(1000);
$connection = mysql_connect("$hostname" , "$user" , "$pass" ,"$port") 
or die ("Can't connect to MySQL");
$db = mysql_select_db($dbase , $connection) or die ("Can't select database.");
$file = fopen("med4","r") or exit ("File not found");
$c =0 ;
      while (!feof($file)){
            ++$c;
        $val = fgets($file);
        mysql_query("insert into patientinfo_medicines (medicine) values ('$val')");    
      }
fclose($file);
echo $c;
?>
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MySQL server from command line?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `http://` part shouldn't be in the `$hostname`. Also, using `"$variable_name"` is exactly the same as `$variable_name`, but slower and completely useless. I always wondered why people do that...

Comment: thanx for replying and my code working perfectly on localhost... but i want to insert this file data into server actually im not getting plz help.... and im using amazon through putty there when i right mysql -uroot -pbitnami it open mysql....

Comment: thanx for replying mr.shesek but plz can u tel me the right and good approach... to solve this problem thanx in advance. can u give the sample code... so that i can understand

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons why you are not able to connect to the server.

1. Firewall (iptables) settings on the server prevent external access
2. The MySQL server only listens for local connections
3. There is no MySQL remote user created on the server
4. Your `$hostname` should be `'ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com';`

There might be other reasons as well.

Also, it is generally a bad idea to connect to databases over the internet for reasons varying from security to latency.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'http://ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/' (1)
```

What about to try change your "hosname" to IP adress? Would it help ?

When I'm trying to ping it, it's unreachable

Comment: same error when i try with ipaddress not getting    Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '122.248.220.105' (10060) in C:\websites\medicine\filehandling.php on line 17
Can't connect to MySQL

Comment: because it's unreachable. try to ping it from your cmd :p C:\Users\Genesis>ping 122.248.220.105

Command PING to 122.248.220.105:
Timeout

Comment: i try to ping ip but its working. still the problem.... i mention my php code but problem is with to connect with server.

Comment: what aren't you getting? Just contact your host

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [BitNami AMI](http://bitnami.org/cloud) you will not be able to connect to the MySQL database remotely in a default configuration. For security reasons, we don't enable it (I'm a BitNami developer). In any case if you want to allow remote connections for the database 'fortis'  I would recommend to create a different user that will only have access to that database instead of using the user 'root'. That would be a bit more secure although as Sukumar mentions is better to avoid to give access to MySQL in public machines.

To give remote access to a different user you will need to connect (with putty) to your amazon machine and execute the following commands. I suppose that you are using BitNami (because of your password).

`. /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh` (notice that space between the dot and the command, this will load the BitNami environment).

```
mysql -u root -p -e "grant all privileges on fortis.* to
'fortis_user'@'localhost' identified by 'fortis_password'"
```

The above will create the fortis_user for the database with access from localhost.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "grant all privileges on fortis.* to
'fortis_user'@'%' identified by 'fortis_password'"
```

This above will give access to the fortis_user for the database from any other ip.

Now you should be able to connect with:

```
$hostname='ec2-122-248-220-105.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com';
//$port='3306';
$user='fortis_user';//// specify username
$pass='fortis_password'; //// specify password
$dbase='fortis'; //// specify database name
```